# Read files in a loop using part of their name to create a new variable in large combined data frame using fread(cmd=...) and rbindlist

Tags: r, fread, rbindlist

I am trying to read multiple files from a folder and combine them into one large data frame. I would like the new data frame to have a column that identifies from which file it comes, in my case, the year which is part of the file name.

```r
require(data.table)

filelist <- list.files(path="mywd")

df <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(filelist)){

      tempdata <-fread(filelist[i], stringASFactors = FALSE, colClasses = list(character = 13))

      setattr(tempdata,'YEAR', c(i+2002))

      df <- rbindlist(list(df, tempdata), use.names = T, idcol = "YEAR")
}
```

I get multiple errors saying:

*Taking input= as a system command ('file name') and a variable has been used in the expression passed to `input=`. Please use **fread(cmd=...)**. There is a security concern if you are creating an app, and the app could gave a malicious user, and the app is not running in a secure environment; e.g. the app is running as root. Please read item 5 in the NEWS file for v1.11.6 for more information and for the option to suppress this message.*

I do not know where to look for the NEWS and could not work the cmd option. The files names are like *"YYYY one two three with four.dsv".* 
Thank you in advance for your help! :)

**UPDATE** I have now played a bit with the cmd option for *fread()*. I have not managed to fix my problem but perhaps I am in the good direction.

Trying to adapt to file name with spaces "YYYY one two three with four.dsv"

```r
require(data.table)

filelist <- list.files(path="mywd")

df <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(filelist)){

      tempdata <-fread(sprintf('%4d one two three with four.dsv', i+2002), stringASFactors = FALSE, colClasses = list(character = 13))

      setattr(tempdata,'YEAR', c(i+2002))

      df <- rbindlist(list(df, tempdata), use.names = T, idcol = "YEAR")
}
```

Which gives a new error saying for each year:

*'2003' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

And *warnings()* say execution failed with error code 1.

Comment: It works with no spaces in the name files, even though the code is not yet working well as it is creating several YEAR columns.

Comment: If you want `fread()` to work with spaces, you may want to try enclosing the name in double quotes, i.e. `fread(sprintf('"%4d one two three with four.dsv"', i+2002), ...`